# Redirect Traffic to Different pages bases on the address used

Tags: php, apache, redirect, webserver

I Have a webserver running on my raspberry pi and I am using it for multiple projects.  I can easily enough access the different pages with something of the from ip-addrss\project-name.php.  I was looking to eliminate the ip address and found I could set up the domain names on my router. so http:/projector or projector.local redirects to the raspberry pi.  The problem is it always goes to the default page. I can setup http:/ProjectA and http:/ProjectB but they both go to index.php. is there a way in php to redirect based on the url used to get there. so index.php would redirect to projectA.php or projectB.php depending on which url was used?  I looked through $_SERVER and $_POST but they didn't seem to have the right information. Some research lead me to believe apache could do this but I have experience configuring apache.

Comment: Not sure if `$_POST` would be of any use here since there does not seem to be a form involved. See if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You COULD do it in PHP, by checking $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], but that value can be manipulated by who is making the request. So I can access `http://ProjectA` while specifying the headers `host: ProjectB` or similar, and you will think that it's `ProjectB`.
In fact, if you look at the HTTP request, `HTTP_HOST` is the only way one would determine the domain name. So it doesn't matter if you do it in PHP or Apache.

In Apache, you could do it by enabling `vhosts` mod for apache. If you're running linux, the command line might be something like this `a2enmod vhosts_alias`. This will allow you to configure different hosts, determined by the `host` HTTP header, and IP. Each virtual host points to an individual directory. You can have 2 hosts pointing at the same directory, but you'd have to modify the directory properties, something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName ProjectA
    ServerAlias www.ProjectA #you can skip this line if it doesn't apply
    DocumentRoot /var/www/foo
    <Directory "/var/www/foo">
        DirectoryIndex ProjectA.php
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I didn't try to configure the same directory differently for 2 different hosts. My instincts say that it should work, but it may not.

Here's a guide on how to configure virtual hosts on Ubuntu. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

I have no idea how different it is on Raspberry Pi. But the apache config files should have exactly the same syntax and rules. Only paths and commands might differ.

Comment: Thanks I have that working quite nicely from php I might try to configure Apache one of these days but for now it works!  As you noted I can fool it by calling out the wrong host in the HTTP request. but its just a local server for things like turning my projector on so i'm not too worried about it.